# how to map properly url param in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, url, oauth-2.0

I'm new to web development and I don't know how to map this url in spring.
this url that I get, is the url that github sends me after the user authorizes my app to make requests on his behalf.

http://localhost:5000/DashboardApp/app/index.html?code=ABCD#/home

```
  @RequestMapping(value="http://localhost:5000/DashboardApp/app/index.html")
  public void callback(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
      System.out.println("The authorization code is : " + code);
      }
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, because the method `callback` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `@RequestMapping`, you should specify just a path relative to your application root:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/app/index.html")
```

Domain, port and context path will be resolved at runtime.